# Cannot duplicate all ouput to a file with tar/pigz

Tags: command-line, bash, tar, tee

I'm using in my script:

```
tar cfh - "$SRC_DIR" --exclude-from <(find $SRC_DIR -size +$EXCLUDE_MB_FILES) | pigz -9 --quiet --keep --recursive --rsyncable > $BACKUP_TARGER_DIR/$ARC_NAME | tee $LOG_FILE
```

But `LOG_FILE` is empty. Why?

Comment: Your sending `pigz`'s output to `$BACKUP_TARGER_DIR/$ARC_NAME`, so nothing goes to the pipe to `tee`. `$LOG_FILE` is naturally empty.

Comment: Wait, but I see in console text/lines. I want this output write to file.

Comment: That would be pigz's stderr

Comment: I think you right partially. It's tar's stderr, not pigz (pigz has key -quiet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split command:

```
find -L $SRC_DIR -size +$EXCLUDE_MB_FILES > $EXCLUDE_LIST 2>> $LOG_FILE
RC=$?;
if [[ $RC != 0 ]]; then
    error find $RC
fi

tar cfh $TAR_FILE "$SRC_DIR" --exclude-from $EXCLUDE_LIST &>> $LOG_FILE
RC=$?;
if [[ $RC != 0 ]]; then
    error tar $RC
fi

pigz -9 --quiet --keep --recursive --rsyncable $TAR_FILE &>> $LOG_FILE
RC=$?;
if [[ $RC != 0 ]] || [ ! -f $GZ_FILE ]; then
    error pigz $RC
fi

mv $GZ_FILE $BACKUP_TARGER_DIR/$ARC_NAME
RC=$?;
if [[ $RC != 0 ]]; then
    error mv $RC
fi
```

Comment: You could have done `(tar cfh - "$SRC_DIR" --exclude-from <(find $SRC_DIR -size +$EXCLUDE_MB_FILES) | pigz -9 --quiet --keep --recursive --rsyncable > $BACKUP_TARGER_DIR/$ARC_NAME) 2>"$LOG_FILE"` without splitting up

Comment: Hm, I'm confused. I already try it. But get empty log file. Are you sure that your way redirect stderr of find and tar too?